# JavaScript - jquery calender not showing in table- nested input, only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datepicker

I have an input- field, nested, in a table, made a datepicker, with jquery.
It does not work, in Firefox 41.0.2 but in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m and in IE 11.
I cannot show the source, cause it's from work.

Generally I just create a table, with JavaScript, make the rows sortable and give the nested input- fields unique id's.
Then html is assigned, to the DOM and the input- fields made datepickers, via id's.
Clicking on it, the datepicker just shows up in IE and Chrome.
Putting a datepicker- input somewhere else, in the site, FF opens it, too.

I raised the z-index of .ui-datepicker and ui-datepicker-div, up to 1000, which does not work.
Firebug says, the inputs get class "hasDatepicker".
Console does not throw an error. No warning either.

Is there an Firefox/ datepicker- issue, with tables ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Asking for work is not so good here, it seems. Sorry, did not want to bother anyone.

Comment: Hello again, if anybody is running into the same problem, that Firefox does not let you click, into Input/ Textarea- fields, which are within a jquery  sortable somewhat construct, the solution, for me, was, to delete the disableSelection()- call.